# How to use MySQL subquery in JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

Example query:

```
SELECT country 
FROM data 
WHERE city LIKE 
(SELECT LEFT ('jakartada',7));
```

Example in JDBC:

```
String sql = " SELECT country FROM data WHERE city LIKE (SELECT LEFT ('?',7)) ";
PreparedStatement ps = koneksi.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1,     city    );
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Why this doesn't work properly?

Answer (score 3):

There is no parameter within the prepared statement, however the code attempts to set a parameter.  Try adding a parameter to the statement.

```
String sql = " SELECT country FROM data WHERE city LIKE (SELECT LEFT (?,7)) ";
PreparedStatement ps = koneksi.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1,     city    );
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Or try removing the statement setting the parameter:

```
String sql = " SELECT country FROM data WHERE city LIKE (SELECT LEFT ('jakartada',7)) ";
PreparedStatement ps = koneksi.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Then catch the SQLException?

Comment: @Kevin Bowersox : how to adding parameter on statement,can you give an example with that query?

Comment: @hd1 It will be get cached as its checked exception. What I am concerned about is  `%` sign.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're making this harder than it needs to be, and at the same time you're missing something. Is this what you're trying to do?

```
 SELECT country FROM data WHERE city LIKE 'jakarta%'
```

That is, are you looking for the country column from every row where the city name starts with 'jakarta'?  If so, don't forget the `%` sign.  If you don't include the `%` sign, then

```
 SELECT country FROM data WHERE city LIKE 'jakarta'
```

and

```
 SELECT country FROM data WHERE city = 'jakarta'
```

mean exactly the same thing as each other, and the `LIKE` operator is pointless; you may as well use the `=` operator.

So, it seems to me the MySQL query you want is

```
 SELECT country FROM data WHERE city LIKE CONCAT(LEFT('jakartada',7),'%')
```

to add the % sign.  You don't need the subselect in this case.

Like you pointed out, the Java code you need then is:

```
 String sql = "SELECT country FROM data " . 
              "WHERE city LIKE CONCAT(LEFT(?,7),'%')";

 PreparedStatement ps = koneksi.prepareStatement(sql);
 ps.setString(1,     city    );
 ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
 ... process the rs records ...
 rs.close();  /* please don't forget to close your result sets */
```

Comment: yeahh,you know what i mean,but your java code not work properly

Comment: I use this query for my program to predict when an error occurs typing input, so the system will break the string by taking a few characters on the right or left of the input string and after that do the matching in accordance with the data in the database.

I tried this query and runs well in MySQL, so I tried to implement in java but it does not work well.
for example I have an input "jakartada" where this is the wrong input then the system will check to take some of the characters of the string on the left and right to find the correct data is "jakarta" .

Answer (score 1):

use this link for your solution and this query

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c79ab/10

```
SELECT country FROM data
WHERE city LIKE CONCAT(LEFT('jakartada',7),'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you quotes in your prepared statement when setting values at runtime... Otherwise it will take it as input only not for ps position... Remove single quotes from your question mark...